# Python Tweepy API Functions

Tags: python, tweepy

I have been playing around with Tweepy for a couple of days. Wanted to create a simple program to follow my followers:

```
for follower in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers).items():
    follower.follow()
```

This is working fine. However, I was looking at the Tweepy API reference on their official site and I do not find any mention of this `follow` function. I do see something called `create_friendship`. Are these two different? If not, why do two different functions exist for the same purpose?

Sorry for asking such a silly question but I am a beginner.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, Tweepy documentation is not (yet) complete. But since it's opensource, we can find the method in its [GitHub](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/4293cb0fabb41d75da0f576e1dc7ed5479769156/tweepy/models.py#L186). As you can see, `follow` calls `create_friendship`:

```
def follow(self):
    self._api.create_friendship(user_id=self.id)
    self.following = True
```

Why they both exist? It's for your own convenience. The `follow` method is convenience when you already have a `User` model just like your example. But in other case where you only have id/screen_name/user_id, `create_friendship` is more convenience because you don't have to create/get the model first.

Comment: Thank you very much. Will look into Tweepy's GitHub for further details.